# Delegate in UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I present modally UIViewController with workout. When user dismiss this VC I need to hold unfinished workout and present small UIView with size exactly the same as UITabBar in all others view controllers. This UIView has a button which should instantiate unfinished workout. The problem is that delegate doesn't work.

```
class BackToWorkoutButton: UIView {
    
    weak var delegate: BackButtonWorkoutDelegate?
    var routine: Routine!

    init(frame: CGRect, routine: Routine) {
        self.routine = routine
        super.init(frame: frame)
        customInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    private func customInit() {
        
        let xibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BackToWorkoutButton", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView
        xibView.frame = self.bounds
        addSubview(xibView)
    }
    
    @IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
// THIS DELEGATE DOESN'T WORK
        delegate?.backToWorkout()
    }
}

class WorkoutCoordinator {

 func instantiateUnfinishedWorkout() {
 let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        guard let tabBar = navigationController.tabBarController else { return print("Tabbar nil") }
        let height = tabBar.tabBar.frame.height
        let child = NewWorkoutCoordinator(routine: temporaryRoutine, navigationController: navigationController, removeCoordinatorWith: removeChild, workoutViewBarProtocol: self)
        let view2 = BackToWorkoutButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (tabBar.tabBar.frame.origin.y) - height, width: window.frame.width, height: height), coordinator: child, routine: routine)
        view2.delegate = self
         tabBar.view.addSubview(view2)
}

}
```

Comment: `delegate?.backToWorkout()` is `delegate` nil or is the method `backToWorkout()` not called? Is `WorkoutCoordinator` still "alive" (not release too soon)? Maybe put `view2` as a `var` of the `WorkoutCoordinator`?

Comment: Both. Delegate and all variables inside UIView become nil and backToWorkout() is not called